# div doesn't display 100% width when the content width in other div is greater than 100%

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I make DIV width 100% (body width) with CSS? Currently, my div (.MainHeading) width is set as 100%, but it doesn't display like 100% when the content width in another div is greater than the screen size. It just displays in top-left corner.

I've been searching for the solution for some time but I haven't found it yet...

This is my CSS:

```
body 
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.MainHeading
{
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:Gray;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height:auto;
min-height:93px;
width:100%;
}
.Body-Area
{
margin:0 auto;
overflow:visible;
width:950px;
max-width:950px;
height:100%;
min-height:395px;
}
.Container
{
display:table-row;
position:relative;
}
.Mid-Div
{
display:table-cell; 
position:relative;  
padding-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;
float:left; /*for IE 7 & 9 Compatible View*/
overflow-x:auto;/*for IE 8*/
vertical-align:top;
width:100%;
max-width:950px;    
overflow:hidden;
}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div class="MainHeading">
    </div>
    <div class="Body-Area">
        <div class="Container">
            <div class="Mid-Div">
                 <img align="bottom" width="1224" vspace="1" lang="en"  hspace="1" height="332" border="1" src="images/cover2.png" alt="Test" id="imgtest" dir="ltr" />
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run this code and it seems to be fine. The heading div is 100% of the body, which in turn is the full width of the viewport.

**Update in reply to comment:**

I finally see now. You have a mistaken assumption, which is that the image is expanding the body. In fact, your body remains at 950px, even with min-width, because the image is not expanding it. So the 100% is actually correct.

The problem isn't the width setting, it's the float on your Mid-div. Floating takes it out of layout, so the contents of that div are not pushing the page larger. You have to find a method that eliminates the float. You also have a max-width of 950, so if you want the body to grow, you have to get rid of that. Otherwise the image will simply clip. If clipping the image is acceptable, then perfect. :-)

My advice, and I'm sure it sucks to hear this, is to rethink your approach from the ground up. Adding a bit here and a bit there, subtracting something, changing a value... these are going to lead to a mess. The problem you want to solve should be very simple and require not too many rules... write some "requirements" (what must the page do, and under what circumstances) and then rewrite the CSS.

In any event, here's a "proof of concept" branch of sandeep's fiddle without the float; the image is clipped rather than expanding body (due to min-width):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMWpW/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The width of the image inside <div class="Mid-Div"> is 1224.  The screen width is 1345.  Because I set the width of <div class="Body-Area"> as 950px, the image start showing from left margin about 15%.  So, the image displays overflow from screen width and heading div doesn't display 100%. You can see it by replacing src="images/cover2.png" with actual image src="http://www.doctorswithoutborders.org/images/news/2008/Myanmar-Burma-Cyclone-Nargis.jpg".

Comment: I think you need to clarify your problem. Your body is 950, .MainHeading is 950, which is 100%.

Comment: Hi Greg Pettit, thanks for your answer.  Body is 100%. .MainHeading is 100%. Only .Body-Area is 950.  My problem is when the image inside .Body-Area is overflow from viewport width, .MainHeading cannot fill to the expanded area.

Comment: Hi Greg Pettit, Great answer!  Now, I understand it clearly.  Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Define `min-width` to your **body**. write like this:

```
body{
 min-width:950px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZMWpW/

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.  I set min-width:950px; to body.  But I doesn't work.  You can see my result by replacing src="images/cover2.png" to src="http://www.doctorswithoutborders.org/images/news/2008/Myanmar-Burma-Cyclone-Nargis.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering like a year after this question was asked, but I just had the same issue and found this post; the base for my answer is the one already published by sandeep.

Define `min-width` to 950 on your `.MeanHeading` div, that should do the trick, however it has a downside, it would be the minimum width of your heading if you dont have a problem with this I think you are good to go.

Comment: @neustroev.ai he basically said that his answer is *based off* of a [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9987089/384985) one by [sandeep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/567751/sandeep)